# Youtube Chromeless Player With Mobile Browser Support

Tags: javascript, youtube

Basically I would like to display a chromeless video on desktop browsers and a fallback that works for mobile browsers.  The default video on the iPad is fine.  But by displaying the chromelesss youtube player for desktop browsers, you get the blue brick for iOS, http://www.theipadguide.com/images/content/announce-noflash.jpg.

Ultimately I could detect if flash is supported and insert the regular YouTube embed code for the iPad and iPhone (assuming it would replace the embed code with its custom YouTube player) but that feels wrong.

How could I successfully detect if the browser is replacing the YouTube embed code with its on player?

You can see the player in action on this web page:
http://technobolt.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/youtube-embed-wp7.jpg

Typically the iPhone displays the blue puzzle piece:  http://www.theipadguide.com/images/content/announce-noflash.jpg

This is info on the chromeless YouTube player for desktop.

- http://badsyntax.github.com/jquery-youtube-player/
- http://www.viget.com/inspire/youtube-chromeless-video-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps include the regular YouTube embed code as the alt html, e.g.:

```
<object ...> <!-- chromeless embed ->
    <!-- regular embed here ->
</object>
```

Comment: so you are suggesting if the video successfully cues, you would basically hide the mobile fallback video.

Comment: What I am suggesting, is to put the regular youtube embed inside the chromeless embed's object or embed tag, such that if the chromeless embed fails the regular youtube embed will work. So yeah, basically what you said.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're looking for this: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#chromeless_player

Comment: The issue is that chromeless youtube player doesn't work on mobile devices.  I fail to see what you are looking to that fixes that issue.  It just the documentation for setting up the chromeless player the first time.

Comment: There is a HTML5 version of Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/html5.  You could look at their HTML5 source code, and try to stripe out the chrome from there.

Comment: Youtube is dynamically generating the mp4 videos urls.  Even if you could create a cross browser chromeless experience, you wouldn't be able link to the create mp4 video in the player.